# Reducing rendertime: multiple materials vs one complex material

Tags: rendering, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

BI render. I have one object combined from many meshes with their own materials (textures varies from 1024*1024 to 512x512 px). What is the best way for reducing rendertime:

1. Left everything as it is
2. Bake all to one diffuse texture (1024*1024 or bigger?) and create alpha, specular, reflective, etc. maps to keep things separate

Maybe it doesn't worth it and difference in render time will be bare noticeable?

Comment: Will you use this for the standard Blender Render Engine, or the Blender Game Engine? Regardless, remember this; More things = higher RAM usage/less CPU usage. Less things (Combined into a complex object) = less RAM usage/more CPU usage.

Comment: Only a test can tell